# Error message when debugging .NET Core RC2 web application in Service Fabric

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I finally managed to get a .NET Core RC2 web application uploaded to Service Fabric. But as soon as it is deployed I get the following error message in Visual Studio:

[image: Error message]

In the Service Fabric Explorer I get the following error in the partition for the web application:

[image: Error message Service Fabric]

My ServiceManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest Name="WebApplicationPkg"
             Version="1.0.0"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ServiceTypes>
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="WebApplicationType" />
  </ServiceTypes>

  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>WebApplication.exe</Program>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
  </CodePackage>
  <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.0" />

  <Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" />
    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
</ServiceManifest>
```

And my project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
  }
}
```

My Progam.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I did wrong? Where is this error comming from?
When I run the application locally it's fine. Just as soon as I deploy it to Service Fabric I get these errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into a similar problem earlier. I am yet to find out the particular problem. I suspect it is because the service does not register itself onto the service fabric runtime, causing the number of healthy partitions (for the particular service) to be below the specified value (InstanceCount in your application manifest).

I solved it by creating a communication listener based on the OwinCommunicationListener provided in the SDK. My implementation is very similar to what you will find in the [Hosting repo by weidazhao (David)](https://github.com/weidazhao/Hosting). I recommend that because it seems to be close enough to what will be in the official SDK.